# Passing parameter (string) to GetAsync()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm new on creating Web Api's and I need to pass a string to GetAsync method but I don't know what should I add to WebApiConfig file and how on GetAsync after the change. I've searched here but I've found nothing that helped me. Can anyone help me please?

My procedure:

```
private async void registrarServico(string nomeServico)
{
    using (HttpClient clientGet = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpClient clientSet = new HttpClient())
    {
        clientGet.BaseAddress = new Uri("api/ControladorServico/GetServico");
        var respostaGet = await clientGet.GetAsync("", nomeServico); //ERROR HERE!
    }
}
```

My WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

My API method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetServico(string nomeServico)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(controladorServicoRep.CONTROLADOR_SERVICOSep.Get(d => d.NOME == nomeServico && d.MAQUINA == nomeMaquina).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your base address doesn't have a server specified... which server do you expect it to connect to? It's also not clear what problem you're facing. "I need to pass a string to GetAsync" - do you mean you have a string you *want* to pass, but you're not sure what to do with it? Or that the API is forcing you to pass in a string, but you don't know what to pass? And you say "ERROR HERE" but you haven't told us anything about what error you're seeing...

Comment: GetAsyn() method has only one parameter that is a "GetAsync(string requestUri)". I wanted to know how can I add the "nomeServico" parameter along with the "requestUri".

Comment: Well that's the ID, so it needs to be part of the URI you pass in... I think you probably need to read some articles about how routing works in MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well do something like this:

```
public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string uriString) where TResult : class
    {
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        using (var client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Log.Error(response.ReasonPhrase);
                return default(TResult);
            }
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
        }
    }
```

And then you can call this as:

```
var uriString = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "http://hostaddress/api/ControladorServico/GetServico", nomeServico);
var result = await GetAsync<YourModel>(uriString);
```