# Method Not Allowed when calling Post using the Build api

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using TFS2018 and calling the build api like this

```
internal void UpdateSourceBranches(List<BuildDefinition> defs)
        {
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tfsUser, tfsPass) })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tfsServer);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    foreach (var def in defs)
                    {
                        var buildId = def.Id;
                        var sourceBranch = $"$/{def.Repository.Name}/{def.Project.Name}";
                        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "BuildConfiguration", "release" },
                        { "BuildPlatform", "x86|x64|ARM" },
                        { "system.debug", "true" }
                    };

                        var jsonParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

                        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", buildId.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sourceBranch", sourceBranch),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parameters", jsonParams)
                        });

                        var response = client.PostAsync($"DefaultCollection/{def.Repository.Name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.0-preview.1", content);
                        var s = response.Result;
                    }                  
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }
        }
```

But getting the following response

> {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Pragma: no-cache
>   X-TFS-ProcessId: ActivityId: X-TFS-Session: X-VSS-E2EID:
>   X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN X-VSS-UserData: :user Persistent-Auth:
>   true Lfs-Authenticate: NTLM X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2018 14:37:16 GMT P3P:
>   CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS
>   DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT" Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Content-Length: 93 Allow: GET Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 }}

Any idea why I am getting Method Not Allowed ?

Here is the bad response:

> {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Pragma: no-cache
>   X-TFS-ProcessId: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   ActivityId: 
>   xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   X-TFS-Session: 
>   xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   X-VSS-E2EID: 
>   xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
>   X-VSS-UserData:  xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx:user
>   Persistent-Auth: true   Lfs-Authenticate: NTLM
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff   Cache-Control: no-cache   Date: Tue,
>   13 Mar 2018 09:21:53 GMT   P3P: CP="...multiple keywords"   Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/10.0   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319   X-Powered-By:
>   ASP.NET   Content-Length: 547   Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8   Expires: -1 }}

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your POST is the issue, try using a GET

Comment: Yes you are right POST is the problem. Any idea how I can solve that?

Comment: Use GetAsync instead of PostAsync

Comment: Ok, but how do I pass in the parameters if I use Get?

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003569/passing-parameter-string-to-getasync

Comment: Thanks, but why is post not allowed??

Answer (score 1):

You should use `api-version=2.0` instead of `3.0-preview.1`.

Update code snippet:

```
string con = "{\"definition\": {\"id\": 47},\"sourceBranch\":\"$/CeceScrum/TestCaseProject\",\"parameters\":\"{\\\"BuildConfiguration\\\":\\\"release\\\",\\\"BuildPlatform\\\":\\\"any cpu\\\",\\\"system.debug\\\":\\\"false\\\"}\"}";
                        var patchValue = new StringContent(con, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                        string _credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "domain\\username", "password")));
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _credentials);
                        var method = new HttpMethod("POST");

                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, "http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/CeceScrum/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0") { Content = patchValue };

                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

                       string re= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT if I change to api-version=2.0 I get a bad request...

Comment: Bad request means your api is not correct. Are you going to queue builds for all your build definition? Could you try to set a breakpoint to check what did you get for `content` and share it?

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT there were only basic headers in the content field. I added the response to the question...

Comment: Hi @CeceDon-MSFT now it works, but I assumed this would fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068293/tfs2018-why-is-shelveset-name-empty . Is it possible to fill out the shelveset as well?

Comment: Yes, the `sourceBranch` you specify here will apply to the `Shelvset name`.

Comment: But even so the shelve set name appears empty in the queue dialog after updating the source branch. It should be filled out or not?

Comment: @doorman The queue dialog is not a part of build definition, it won't save after you queue build. You could check the `Source` in the build details and you'll see the source branch you have queued.